# How to take mysqldump of specific tables across all databases and restore them to a a single database?

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, mysqldump

I need to take a mysqldump of specific tables across all databases in a cluster.
In this case the cluster has more than 300+ databases. And I need to take the dump of `table1` and `table2` from each of the 300+ databases.

Then I need to restore the dump to another cluster, to a single database having `table1` and `table2`. Essentially, the data from the tables in the 300+ databases above needs to be consolidated to the tables in a single database in this cluster.

**Example:**
Cluster A has information about a company's employees in a table called `Employees` which is spread out across databases that represent the company's locations, like database `Los Angeles`, `Austin`, `New York` etc...

I need to take a dump of all the `Employee` tables across the location databases.

Then in Cluster B, there will be a database called `USA` in which there will be a table called `Employees` which will have a union of all the Employee information from the above dump.

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump cannot do what you ask. It's meant for backups, and whatever transforms data is not a backup.

But all you have to do is to create a view, and then backup the contents of the view.

The following SQL creates the view:

```
SELECT
    @view_definition := GROUP_CONCAT('(SELECT * FROM ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.employee)' SEPARATOR ' UNION ') AS view_definition
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'employee';
SET @view_definition := CONCAT('CREATE VIEW usa.employee AS ', @view_definition);
SELECT @view_definition;
PREPARE stmt_create_view FROM @view_definition;
EXECUTE stmt_create_view;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_create_view;
```

mysqldump doesn't backup views. But you can backup an `employee` table structure with [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html) and the view contents into a CSV file with [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html).

To create the table into cluster B, run the `CREATE TABLE` statement and load the CSV file contents with [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).